# How to make room bright with lights

Tags: light

The lights in my room is very dim,and also I think as per my eye condition I see a little less bright One of the reason is the installed light connection don't support much load and working from home, I feel it is too dark. As I live in UK it is mostly cloudy so window doesn't help much.

What are other ways I can make my room brigther?

Edit: for clarity my eye condition is called [keratoconus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratoconus), **Strong Graphics**

Comment: Mentioning what eye condition that you have may assist in providing better answers. Some eye conditions cause people to see less well in dim or very bright conditions.

Comment: @JacquesRamsden I think that is my judgment as while diriving in rain, my visibility is really less. I will update the question as well but I have keratoconus

Answer (score 2):

> One of the reason is the installed light connection don't support much load

This is false.

There are two reasons why a light fixture or its connection can't support enough load.

Firstly, it may have limited current. It's perfectly feasible for the wiring to only support let's say 2.5 amperes. Lights use very low current and therefore thin wires can be used. But 2.5 amperes at 230 volts is already 575 watts. 575 watts of LED lights will make your room very bright with light. I cannot imagine a situation where the wiring could support only less than 2.5 amperes, since the wiring would need to be microscopically thin then. Besides, more common are 10 ampere circuits. 2.5 amperes would be an extraordinary case.

Secondly, the light fixture can have limited heat dissipation. Remember that most lights, yes including even LED lights, mainly create heat and light is only a side product. LEDs are more efficient than CFLs which are more efficient than halogen bulbs which are more efficient than incandescent bulbs. But all of them, including LEDs, create primarily heat. Only an insignificant fraction of the energy goes to light. However, in times when incandescents were the standard bulbs it was very hard to find a light fixture that can't have at least let's say 40 watt bulb. Usually 60 watt bulbs are most common. 40 or 60 watts of LEDs in a bulb will make a very bright bulb. In fact, so bright you can't find one. Usually 17 - 20 watts is already very exceptionally bright.

It is theoretically possible that today some manufacturer could label some light fixture to accept only let's say 14 watts. Most likely this is overly cautious: I cannot imagine a light fixture where one cannot safely mount a 20 watt LED bulb, after all it only creates about half of the heat of a 40 watt incandescent bulb.

I also like lots of light. My solution has been this: I always buy only light fixtures that can accept three light bulbs. They may be getting more difficult to find in this day and age of LED lights, but not impossible to find. Then at each light bulb socket, I mount the brightest LED bulb I can find, usually those make around 2500 lumens each. So 7500 lumens per light fixture.

This doesn't help if your light fixtures are permanently mounted and you live in a rental apartment. But it does help if you can mount your own light fixtures.

Note that 2500 lumens  per bulb and 7500 lumens per fixture is very bright. In fact, so bright that you should use light fixtures that have a glass that makes the light more diffuse. If the light fixture has the bulb directly exposed or behind fully transparent glass, the bulbs are so bright they make your eyes hurt when looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

Use low wattage LED bulbs that have a high lumen count. Today you can buy house LED bulbs (120 volt) that are 1000 to 1500 lumens. Color temperature also matters and LED bulbs come in a variety of color temperatures. Measured in `Kelvins" a 6.5K bulb will emit a bright white light while a 2.7K bulb will emit a yellowish warm or softer light. I would suggest starting with a 5K example. that would greatly illuminate your room although it may also give it a 'cold' feel.

Comment: Hi, I thought Waatage  = lumens, the more W we have the more bright it will be and if W , then there is a limit on lamp socket u can put on, like Max 7W

Comment: No, wattage ≠ lumens. An obsolete incandescent tungsten filament bulb that puts out 400 lumens might draw around 60 watts, but an LED light that gives out 400 lumens might draw about 6 watts. This means you can install mush brighter LED lighting, for less load on the electricity supply. But if you already use a 7 watt LED lamp, the light output is going to be pretty feeble. You won't get a "brightly lit room" with one, or even two or three of them.

Comment: ... Most domestic lamp sockets are not limited to 7 watts (more like 60 or 100) – that limit is due to the *heat* that is given out, and the wattage is more directly related to the *heat*. The lumens are related to wattage by the *efficiency* of the device.

Comment: With incandescent bulbs wattage has less of an effect on lumen output due to their inefficiency. Going from a 40-watt incandescent bulb to 60 watt incandescent will give you 4oo more lumens where as going from a 7 watt LED bulb to a 15 watt LED bulb would multiply the lumen output to 1000-1200 lumens. Watts=amperage x voltage so we don't draw watts, we draw amperage. Power is measured in watts.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the number of lights rather than increase the brightness of a small number of them.

Modern LED fittings can be placed around the room, or use LED ribbons along the edge of the ceiling.

Multiple lights will not only increase the overall brightness of the room but also reduce shadows by sending light from many directions.  I find this helps me enormously.